# Why does The whole code of a component get vanished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, hardware

What is just happend there could anybody explain? Is it a problem from VS Code or a Hardware issue. Though my Hdd sometimes shows undetected (I am not sure is it because malfunction of HDD or anything else.)

[image]

After HDD issues (undetected) when I re-insert HDD connection then this page showed like that. I face the same issues several times. Could anyone tell me the source of that problem? & How to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

> What is just happend there could anybody explain?

A file being replaced by NUL (null characters) is a sign of filesystem corruption.

> I face the same issues several times. Could anyone tell me the source of that problem? & How to resolve that?

If you're having other hard drive symptoms too, yep, your hard drive is breaking. Back up everything you need from there and get a new one ASAP.